# How to add cpd4j 6.1.0 API to Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, cdp, web-folders

I am working with a Spring Boot application where I use cdp4j 3.0.15
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.webfolder/cdp4j

I have installed Chrome in a docker container and can access it thru localhost:9222.
I would like to use this browser with my application but I can´t understand how to set it up.

I found a class Options.Builder (here: https://webfolder.io/cdp4j/javadoc/io/webfolder/cdp/Options.html) which seems to be in cdp4j 6.1.0 API but I can´t understand how to add this to my project.

I can see that in Options.Builder there is a method called browserExecutablePath() which I thought I might be able to add localhost:9222 and try.

I would like to use the Chrome in the docker instead of the local chrome.

I have googled around and tried to find the jar for cdp4j 6.1.0 API without any success.

I have difficult to find any good documentation around this.

Answer (score 0):

After some further investigation and reading on their page I found out that the version I used was free version and you need to buy license for the newer versions.